# Problema al clonar WordPress con Xampp

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

He clonado un proyecto que tenía en `midominio.com` a mi `localhost/midominio` con Xampp. Pero cuando intento acceder a la ruta `localhost/midominio` me redirecciona automáticamente a `midominio.com`

Ya modifiqué en la tabla `wp_options` las opciones `siteurl` y `home` pero esto no resuelve mi problema.

**¿Como puedo resolver este problema?**

Answer (score 0):

Asumo que es un problema de cache, ve a tu localhost, si estas en Windows presiona F12 o click derecho -> inspeccionar, en el icono de carga/refresh del sitio da click derecho y selecciona vaciar la cache y cargar de manera forzara, eso reiniciara el cache de todo tu localhost, el problema debería eliminarse, prueba también en incognito para revisar si es eso, si aun así persiste, intenta reiniciar el archivo .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Si hiciste todo lo anterior, seguramente es el caché de tu navegador. Intenta ingresar a la misma url `localhost/midominio` desde el modo incógnito de tu navegador. Ya deberías de verlo bien.